# Load Path from Textbox to Listview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, listview

First of all, i have tried to search around for a long time for this, but without success..

I have a Textbox with a saved path (databinding), and a ListView. When i click on a item in my DataGridView the path in the Textbox changed to that one i saved, ofcourse. But nothing appears in my ListView. I can only see files from the choosen directory, if i browse it everytime, with my button with FolderBrowserDialog.

Can the ListView load the directory, from the path in my textbox automatically, when i select another item in the DataGridView?

My english isnt the best, but i hope you understand.

This is the code i have for browsing my path and get it to the TextBox

```
        private void btnBrowsePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listFiles.Clear();
        metroListView2.Items.Clear();
        using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog() { Description = "Please select your path." })
        {
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtEpisodesPath.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
                foreach(string item in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath))
                {
                    imageList1.Images.Add(System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item));
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(item);
                    listFiles.Add(fi.FullName);
                    metroListView2.Items.Add(fi.Name, imageList1.Images.Count - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i don't think i can edit something in this, to fix the problem, but have to add some extra code, to fix my reqeust. But i don't have any idea to fix it.

UPDATED:

```
private void txtEpisodesPath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listFiles.Clear();
        metroListView2.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath))
        {
            imageList1.Images.Add(System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item));
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(item);
            listFiles.Add(fi.FullName);
            metroListView2.Items.Add(fi.Name, imageList1.Images.Count - 1);
        }
    }
```

I have edited my code to this, but it makes error with the "fbd"

Comment: Your English is fine. Some relevant code would make your question better.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added some code from my project.

Comment: So you are saying that clicking `btnBrowsePath` works fine but not when clicking the `datagridview`?

Comment: When clicking a item(a line) in DataGridView, the path changes in the textbox, but the changed path from the textbox, dosent loads in the listview, i want it to load the new path when cliking another line in DataGridview, if you understand me? It only show the content from the path, if i browse it every time, 
even though the path is already in the TextBox.

Comment: You can have the same code from `btnBrowsePath_Click` to your textbox `TextChanged` event, except ofcource the `txtEpisodesPath.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;` line.

Comment: I will try, take a look on it! :)

Comment: I have tried to figure it out. Take a look at the updated text, and maybe, you can help me, with the last part. I think i'm very close to get it right. I get errors with the fbd line, i dont know how that line should be.

Comment: `but it makes error with the "fbd"`  Always tell us the error.

Comment: You don't need the fdb any more! Just the text of `textbox` which has a valid path. I thought it was obvious. I should have clarified it.

Comment: Im still a beginner in c# coding. I dont know, what to do, with the fbd line. If you can create and answer, with the last thing i missing, i will accept it as answer. If i delete fbd from the line it says "The name 'SelectedPath' dos not exist in the current context"

Comment: Change `fbd.SelectedPath` to `txtEpisodesPath.Text`, if `txtEpisodesPath` is the name of your textbox. Your textbox contains the path so you are using it instead.

Comment: Arh!! Now it works!! Thank you very much. If you will, make a answer, i can accept! :)

Comment: No worries. You have done most of the work except a small detail. Glad i have helped.